# BroadCom MegaRAID SAS 9361-24i Performance Issues

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, megaraid

I have piles of 1TB Samsung mSATA drives that I'm trying to re-purpose for sever storage.  I purchased 24 - [StarTech 25SAT22MSAT](https://www.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/Dual-mSATA-SSD-to-2-5-SATA-RAID-Adapter~25SAT22MSAT) adapters and fitted them with 2 mSATA drives each.  I then enabled the RAID0 feature on each adapter/carrier.

Next I fitted all 24 adapters into a [SuperMicro SC216BAC-R920LPB](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/chassis/2U/216/SC216BAC-R920LPB) chassis and connected the 6 SAS channels from the SAS-216A backplane to a [BroadCom MegaRAID SAS 9361-24i](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-sas-9361-24i) card.

The MegaRAID 9361-24i card has 24 independent SAS/SATA channels and PCIe Gen3 x8 interface. I was expecting to be able to achieve read performance of 4-5 GB/s using this setup. However the fastest read speed I can get is ~2.1 GB/s.

I have been measuring performance using a simple (single threaded) timed cat operation:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
$ time cat data_20GB.bin > /dev/null

real    0m9.780s
user    0m0.165s
sys     0m5.969s
```

as well as using the (multi-thread) application I intended to run on this machine.  Both approaches show similar performance.

One of the first things I did was measure the performance of a single adapter/carrier:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
$ time cat data_20GB.bin > /dev/null

real    0m38.639s
user    0m0.309s
sys     0m10.142s
```

My simple test shows the single-threaded read performance for each adapter is ~530 MB/s. If I round down and say 500 MB/s x 24 = ~12 GB/s. I believe this setup should easily be able to saturate the PCIe Gen 3 x8 link (8 GT/s).

The SuperMicro server is running Ubuntu 16.04 and its boot disks are separate from the RAID array. I have updated the both the Linux driver and the firmware to the latest versions. I have also verified that the RAID card is connected at the expected Gen 3 x8 rate.

The data access pattern for the intended application is mostly large sequential reads.

Here is how I first configured the RAID array:

```
storcli64 /c0 add vd type=raid5 name=storage drives=252:0-23 pdperarray=24 pdcache=on cached wb ra strip=256
```

This configuration gives read performance:

- Simple (timed cat): 1.98 GB/s
- Application: 2.04 GB/s

Here are some of the other things I've tried since then:

- Adjusting many if not all of the combinations of RAID configuration options (RAID0 vs RAID5, cached vs direct, readahead vs no readahead, all of the supported stripe sizes). None of the combinations achieve read speeds higher than 2 GB/s, many are much slower.
- Adjusting configuration options for the RAID card itself. Changing these options had almost no effect on performance.
- Creating an array with only 6 drives.  I still measure read performance at ~2 GB/s, the same as when using all 24 drives. This seems like a major red flag but I can't figure out the cause.  I get the same read performance whether I create the array with drives 0-5 or with drives 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20.
- Creating an array with 12 drives. Same issue, I measure read performance at ~2 GB/s.

I am completely stumped. Does anyone know why the hardware RAID read performance tops out at ~2 GB/s? Any suggestions are welcome.

### Update

I set the RAID card to JBOD mode so each of the 24 drives appears in the OS as an individual block device. I then created a software (mdadm) RAID5 and repeated my performance measurements:

- Simple (timed cat): 4.06 GB/s
- Real application:   5.92 GB/s

This is the performance level I was expecting from the hardware RAID. Maybe I should have saved $500 and just bought the equivalent SAS HBA card instead.

Comment: First, `cat` is a bit dumb - read/write/read/write, so it's spending time writing to `/dev/null`, likely in relatively small chunks.  You can try something like `dd if=... iflag=direct of=/dev/null bs=1m` to bypass the page cache and do IO in larger chunks, reducing the percentage of time spent in null-op `write()` calls. Also, how many PCIe lanes is the card actually using?  What version of the PCIe spec are those lanes actually running at? 2GB/sec is suspiciously close to PCIe 3.0 limits using two lanes and PCIe 2.0 using four lanes.  And a 24-drive RAID5 array?!?

Comment: The Jmicron controller in that RAID adapter is known to be a poor performer. Could you buy 2-4 mSATA to SATA converters (they are only a few dollars each) and try benchmarking again? Please use `fio` to benchmark this time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle using direct IO results in slower read performance. However using dd otherwise as you suggested produces the same ~2GB read performance. As I said above the RAID card is connected at Gen3 x8 (see: https://pastebin.com/yspT9JLh for lspci output).  Due to TLP overhead you're never going to get 2GB/s out of a Gen3 x2 or Gen2 x4 link. Finally, what's wrong with a 24 drive RAID5 array?

Comment: @Bert as I said above, I measured >500 MB/s for each individual drive when connected through the RAID controller in JBOD mode.  500 MB/s for a SATA3 6 Gbps link is pretty good.  I measured ~300 MB/s read performance for each individual mSATA drive.  I'm not sure where this kind of opinion "Jmicron controller in that RAID adapter is known to be a poor performer" is coming from but the performance of each individual adapter/carrier seems fine to me.

Comment: A single Samsung 850 EVO will do about 500MB/s read/write for sequential data. The reviews on Startech's own site for that adapter card complain about performance as well as many other reviews on the internet. JMicron has long been known as one of the lowest performing disk controllers. Also, going over 6-8 in a RAID 5 array starts to get sketchy.

Comment: @Bert This is a digression from my actual question... However, the reason Samsung 850 EVO tops out at ~500 MB/s for read/write it because it's hitting the limits of the SATA3 link.  SATA uses 8B/10B encoding so effective data rate is: 6 Gbps - 1.2 Gbps = 4.8 Gbps (600 MB/s).  That doesn't account for  the actual SATA protocol overhead, so 500 / 600 = 83.3% of effective bandwidth is used for data transfer (rest is protocol overhead).  I'm not sure what the people complaining on the Startech website are expecting.  The 530 MB/s I measured is 88.3% used for data transfer, which is great!

Comment: Turner on the controller Cache as well as the Disk-Cache?